# NTFS alternate data stream usage

Tags: ntfs, alternate-data-stream

We are potentially looking for a solution of how we can identify different versions of a text file on Windows Operating Systems - there are no file attributes that support versioning (e.g. 2.0, 2.1 etc.), but using ADS would allow us to write, for example, version information to an alternative stream within the file. My question, is this a suitable use of ADS, or are there drawbacks or reasons we should not do this? I have been using the information at this link to play around with ADS - https://blog.codefluententities.com/2013/03/14/manipulating-ntfs-alternate-data-streams-in-c-with-the-codefluent-runtime-client/

Comment: [Anybody have a legitimate use for Alternate Data Streams in NTFS?](https://superuser.com/q/186627/241386)

Answer (score 1):

File versions for me are rather metadata than another data stream, so I'd use extended file attributes in this case. Alternate data stream is perfectly suitable for e.g. file preview.

That said, extended attributes have similar drawbacks as ADS (usually lost during the backup or archiving), but unlike ADS, they are supported by FAT32 devices.